How do I protect my endpoints from data harvest?
Sorry for my lack of CSRF understanding, but shouldnt this Sanctum feature make it pretty hard to access my endpoints from other than my frontend app?
Everything is working in my frontend (SPA), endpoints protected with both CSRF token and Bearer auth.
But why am I able to just copy the Headers (Authorization, Origin, Cookie, x-xsrf-token) into Postman and access my endpoints?

Why wouldn't you? You've provided everything to make a legit request?

So there is really no way to protect an endpoint from data harvest / being sure the authorization is used from the SPA/origin?

Your question is better off on security.stackexchange.com - e.g. How to ensure that only my single page app can make requests to an API

To prevent unauthorized access, check the fetch metadata header.
The Sec- header cannot be forged externally, so it also prevents access from Postman.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Fetch_metadata_request_header

Can you explain this more and how this apply to the use-case of OP? Link-only answers are not good answers
